# Generic point mass field (Classical Mechanics)

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

Let's assume I have a particle $p$ with mass $m_p$ at position $\mathbf{x_p}$. I want to assume the most generic field $\mathbf{f}_p(m_p, \mathbf{x}_p, \dot{\mathbf{x}}_p; \mathbf{x})$ generated by this particle such that the equation of motion
\begin{equation}
    \ddot{\mathbf{x}} =\mathbf{f}_p(m_p, \mathbf{x}_p, \dot{\mathbf{x}}_p; \mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
is satisfied for any other particle at position $\mathbf{x}$. Basically, it is a generic
gravitational field. If assume absolute space and time, from invariance under galilean transformations I am able to prove that $\mathbf{f}_p = f_p(m_p, \Vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_p \mathbf{} \Vert) e_r$. I.e., the field must be radial, depend only on the distance to the particle, and cannot depend on the velocity $\dot{\mathbf{x}}_p$ of the particle.

Setting $\mathbf{x}_p=0$ for convenience, then $f_p = f_p(r)$, with $r=\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert$. My question is, is there some assumption I am missing (without relying on GR) from which I could derive that $f_p \propto r^{-2}$? Or does any $f_p(r)$ result in a 'physical' field (conserving energy, etc)?

PD: From the realization that if I assume $f_p(r) = k r^{\alpha}$, then the divergence is
\begin{equation}
    \nabla\cdot \mathbf{f}_p(r) = 
    \begin{cases}
0 \ &\text{if} \ \alpha = -2 \\
k(\alpha + 2)r^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}} &\text{if} \ \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I feel there is something special about the choice $f_p \propto r^{-2}$, but I cannot tell what.

Comment: Math can only bring you so far, you have to also begin to marry such analysis with observed reality like orbits of bodies in the cosmos. You've also not indicated how you got rid of the mass dependence in your analysis as the divergence of an inverse square field should be nonzero if you have a point mass in your domain of integration.